# Fetching string value from JMS header

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I'm trying to figure out how to pull a value out of a JMS header so I can route it to a specific queue dynamically.  I have spent hours trying various methods to extract the value but I haven't been successful.  See the below snippet which explains what I'm after.  Any help or even pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

```
// fetch the queue name from the JMS header
String queue = "jms:queue:" + header("__DestinationQueue").toString();

choice = choice
                .when(header("Match").isEqualTo("true"))
                .id("JMSDaemonOutboundRouteBuilder")
                .to(queue);
        choice = choice
                .otherwise().bean(UnroutableMessageLogAction.class)
                .bean(EndConversationAction.class, "process")
                .bean(ESBMessageCompleteAction.class, "process")
                .to("jms:queue:UNROUTED").endChoice();
```

The data is definitely contained in the header (I've run .isEqualTo comparisons on the header value to confirm this) I am just having issues extracting the actual value into the string.

Comment: If you want to route dynamically, why not use topics instead ? If you are concerned about persistence, use durable subscriptions.  Also, you do not specify what __DesitnationQueue is set to. I think it should be set to the name of the property you are trying to get: "JMSDestination".

Comment: Did you check this one ? It might be similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434130/how-to-make-spring-jms-pick-destination-queue-name-from-annotation-jmslistener

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use toD instead of to which natively allows routing to JMS header values. Link below:

http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html